# Send users input to a page of my site?

Tags: html

I'm really new to creating websites and i'm learning one thing at a time as i need to.
I have a page with a form where the user enters his name in a textbox, chooses a radio button from 3 options and enters a description in another textbox.

I want to place a button at the end and when clicked, send all this fields that the user filled to another page and in it display all this info from different users in a feed.

Can someone tell me the basics of what i should do, so that i can go an make some research and start working.

Comment: It is only HTML? Is JavaScript an option, or something server-side like PHP, ASP, etc.?

Comment: as @BradChristie said, you'll also need to have a server side language such as PHP, ASP, Node.js, etc. JavaScript will be useful, but you probably won't need it.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript and server side languages are options.

Comment: Well, then go read up on the basics of how to process form data with these techniques.